# How to change the value of Png:IHDR.color-type-orig

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick

GraphicsMagick identify returns for the original image the line

```
Png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 6
```

Which parameter is necessary for the convert method so the output will be

```
Png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 3
```

?

Answer (score 0):

The `Png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 3` is palette index. From the [w3 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Chunks.html#C.IHDR).

> Each pixel is a palette index; a PLTE chunk must appear.

So to convert RGBAlpha to Indexed, it could be as simple as...

```
convert rgba_source.png png8:index_output.png
```

or

```
convert rgba_source.png -type Palette index_output.png
```

Which can be verifed with...

```
identify -verbose index_output.png | grep IHDR
```

Comment: Interesting, with the parameter I get Png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 4 instead of 3, what could that be?

Comment: Oh snap! I misread and confused 4 with 3. You're attempting to convert to palette index, NOT GrayAlpha. I'll updated answer

Comment: Thank you, strangely, I still get 4 instead of 3.

Comment: Can you post the image in question? I would guess the alpha mask is preventing Palette.